# Can I have a question migrated to Super User?

Tags: support, status-declined, migration

I would like to have a question migrated from this site to Super User as I feel that it is a highly technical question and I might be able to get an answer there (I haven't been able to get an answer for it here). The question is linked [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172321/no-suitable-display-mode-found-error-for-dawn-of-war-dow-winter-assault)

Comment: For the record, here's the [Super User Meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8389/am-i-able-to-get-more-technical-help-here-on-a-gaming-question-i-have-on-arqade) question as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is older than 60 days and [cannot be migrated.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

Answer (score 2):

Questions about specific video games, no matter how technical, are categorically off topic on SU. So, sorry, but I won't be migrating it.

You could try a bounty, but our track record with tech questions isn't great.

Comment: the question is more concerning my graphics card and one of the mods on Super User said I should ask and I already had a bounty on it

Comment: It even has an error message which people on Super User will be able to follow up more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, it cannot be migrated. You are better off asking the question again on SU, but phrasing it in such a way that it is clearly within the on-topic guidelines on that site. In other words, focus more on the hardware/driver problems and less on the game.